# Problema en la implementación de MatDatepicker: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') for MatDatepickerInputBase

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, observable, material

Estoy tratando de implementar un mat datepicker en mi proyecto y ya he probado casi todos los ejemplos en la documentación de angular material,

pero siempre obtengo este error:

```
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
    at new MatDatepickerInputBase (datepicker.js:3041:1)
    at new MatDatepickerInput (datepicker.js:3286:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.MatDatepickerInput_Factory [as factory].
¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto?
```

Entiendo el por qué, porque no está recibiendo una promesa, pero ¿cómo arreglar esto en la implementación?

No estoy segura de si es un problema con el componente matdatepicker o con la variable de plantilla (template variable) utilizada para la referencia al mat-datepicker, ya que cuando elimino [matDatepicker]="picker" (referencia a #picker de , este error desaparece, pero el componente no consigue construirse correctamente.

Gracias

Carlota

Comment: Es interesante tu pregunta pero si no compartís código de tus modulos  si tu aplicación tiene varios? o tus componentes tiene varios? difícil responderte por favor modifica tu pregunta brindando mas datos .tengo un borrador sobre el tema en https://github.com/nestdanchia/add

Comment: porque hasta puede ser un error de tipeo forma correcta -->``<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mydateB"></mat-datepicker-toggle> <mat-datepicker #mydateB>``

Comment: En este caso no añado código porque hago literlamente copiar pegar del código de la documentación de angular-material. Por eso creo que es un problema de esta plantilla de angular (que ha sido heredada de otro proyecto), al parecer cada vez que pongo variables de plantilla (#miId) en las tags de html da un error parecido, por eso quería saber si se puede controlar este tipo de subscripciones en el angular-material entre componentes del material (en este caso del input del datepicker y el toggle) para que se escuchen un al otro sin usar el #miDatePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La relacion
entre el matInput  el elemento modal y el toogle da error si no están  implementados correctamente los módulos que requiere DatePicker
En el tutorial no indican directamente que modulos se requieren [angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)
La directiva [matDatepicker]  `constructor(elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>, dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>, dateFormats: MatDateFormats, _formField?: MatFormField | undefined);` vincula al input con el elemento modal este no se muestra por default lo vinculamos a un toggle button para mostrarlo o cerrarlo todo esto es una estructura predeterminada que requiere de los modulos necesarios para actuar

```js
// ng g m angular-material --module=app
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ]
})
export class AngularMaterialModule { }
// exportamos
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './angular-material/angular-material.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,
   // FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
//componente
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
 
  myDate = new FormControl(new Date());
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickeryear" 
  placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="myDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle  [for]="pickeryear">
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #pickeryear startView="year"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```